# Out of Memory Error in Galaxy s3 4.0.4

Tags: android

my application have grid view contain lot's of images and as from the Android documentation i understand that android improve the drawable garbage collection and the chance of out of memory is very low compared to os below 3.0 .  Why still i got lot of out of memory in 4.0.4 only- Except this version i won't get single OOM after 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Garbage collector improvement doesn't mean you can now load tonns of bitmaps, cause memory is still limited. I'd recommend you to learn [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) post carefully and follow those practices, then you'll be protected against OOM on any platform. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Egor: i have already referred that document and am following that one except image scaling because am working with an eCommerce app. There is lot of images in App and am showing this with the help of webservice pagination.  Is it still reproducible  above 3.0 if i load lot of images ?

Comment: @SudeepSR, Sorry, don't understand your question.

Comment: that is OOM still in Android OS if we load more images and it is never 100% fixable?

Comment: @SudeepSR, You're right, heap memory is always limited and when you overflow it you'll always get an OOM. This is just how the things work, so there won't ever be a remedy for it. You just need to organize your application such that it recycles bitmaps regularly, caches them when needed and doesn't use more memory than it actually needs. Also I'd recommend you to check your application for memory leaks which also may be the problem.

Comment: Egor One more question: Why i get the OOM in 4.0.4 only except 2.3+

Comment: @SudeepSR, Hard to say, this may be caused by a lot of different issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using only drawable folder for ui. you must be change your rule. Use drawable-xhdpi, drawable-hdpi drawable-mdpi bla bla bla. Samsung galaxy s3 using drawable-xhdpi folder. if your are using only drawable folder for images you will be get frag case memory warning and application give you error out of memory. use memory management tool, change your approach to create user interface on android.  different screen size different drawable folder key subject

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with lots of images, better use lazy images loading.
[Here](https://github.com/desertjim/LazyLoadingGridView) is a sample of images lazyloading in GridView.

Comment: Thanks for u r effort: App is currently running in lazy loading

Comment: If you are still getting OutOfMemory exceptions then there is somewhere you didnt get it right. Could post the code if possible?

Comment: Lazy Loader/ GridView adapter? :The grid view item may have reach above 300